# If Substring not Contain in String python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I've two list of strings, one list is having strings and another list is having its substrings. i want to check whether if substring is not available then print the substring. i'm able to print the available stings.

```
data = ['ab.txt','bbbbbbbbb','ip.txt']
data2 = ['D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New folder\\ab.txt', 'D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New 
folder\\bc.txt', 
'D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New folder\\cd.txt', 'D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New folder 
(2)\\ef.txt', 
'D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New folder (2)\\gh.txt','D:\\ARSDP10\\kml\\New 
 folder\\m.txt', 
'D:\\ARSDP10\\kml\\sag\\ip.txt']
lis = []
for i in data2:
    for j in data:
        if j not in i:
           lis.append(j)
print(lis)
```

Output which i'm looking for is:  `[bbbbbbbbb]`

but i'm getting this

```
['bbbbbbbbb', 'ip.txt', 'ab.txt', 'bbbbbbbbb', 'ip.txt', 'ab.txt', 
 'bbbbbbbbb', 'ip.txt', 'ab.txt', 'bbbbbbbbb', 'ip.txt', 'ab.txt', 
 'bbbbbbbbb', 'ip.txt', 'ab.txt', 'bbbbbbbbb', 'ip.txt', 'ab.txt', 
 'bbbbbbbbb']
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you may have to use set here.

```
data=['ab.txt', 'bbbbbbbbb', 'ip.txt']
data2=['alsdfjasldfjasdab.txt', 'alafdadfdsfasdfhkhgjip.txt']
l=[]
for item1 in data:
    for item2 in data2:
        if item1 in item2:
            l.append(item1)
print(set(data).difference(set(l)))
```

This should give you what's not there.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the path from the files to compare only the filename:

```
 data2 = [i.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1] for i in data2]
 print(data2)

 >> ['ab.txt', 'bc.txt', 'cd.txt', 'ef.txt', 'gh.txt', 'm.txt', 'ip.txt']
```

Compare the two list the the built in function set.difference()

```
 print(set(data).difference(data2))
 >> {'bbbbbbbbb'}
```

Comment: Good one! I wasn't sure if the requirement was only for file paths. Hence, I thought of a generic solution.

Comment: Thanks, it's my first answer in SO!
 I tried to solve his problem not fix the code (I just couldn't). So I made the assumption it's ok to trim the filename and 'bbbbbbbb' is a file

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to check each item of the data list in the data 2 list:

```
data = ['ab.txt','bbbbbbbbb','ip.txt']
data2 = ['D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New folder\\ab.txt', 
         'D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New folder\\bc.txt', 
         'D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New folder\\cd.txt', 
         'D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New folder (2)\\ef.txt', 
         'D:\\ARSDP10\\Exm\\New folder (2)\\gh.txt',
         'D:\\ARSDP10\\kml\\New folder\\m.txt', 
         'D:\\ARSDP10\\kml\\sag\\ip.txt']

presence = [[y in x for y in data] for x in data2]

[[True, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [False, False, True]]
```

Transpose that into 3 lists of 7 values, and then check if any value in each of those 3 lists is True:

```
trans = enumerate([max(x) for x in value])

[(0, True), (1, False), (2, True)]
```

Then, use the index of False in the trans list to get the missing values

```
missing = [data[x[0]] for x in trans if not x[1]]

['bbbbbbbbb']
```